# How can i find the highest number number from a list of numbers in an array?

Tags: c#

How can i find the highest number  from a list of numbers in an array; so far wrote

```
    int[] data = Utilitybook.Utility.fetchData("book01");
    float result=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use linq to sort your data:

```
data = data.OrderByDescending(c => c).ToArray();
```

Then just get your highest and second highest number from it:

```
int highest = data[0];
int second = data[1];
```

Comment: If you are going to use LINQ you may as well just do data.Max();

Comment: @Svek oh yeah, good point :)